# INVALID MODE : s5a869f19a6c57_equivalents - type : sonata_type_collection - mapping :

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I am building a new feature onto a `Symfony 2.8` application using a few Sonata bundles.

My `Page.php` entity definition includes the following mapping:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Equivalent", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="page_equivalent",
 *          joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *          inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="equivalent_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
 *     )
 */
private $equivalents;
```

... and my `PageAdmin.php` file's `configureFormFields()` function contains the following:

```
            ->add('synonyms', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => TextType::class, 'allow_add' => true, 'allow_delete' => true))
            ->add('equivalents', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'label' => "Equivalents",
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'required' => false,
            ), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'targetEntity' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Equivalent',
                'admin_code' => 'app.admin.equivalent',
            ))
```

... which yields the message

> INVALID MODE : s5a869f19a6c57_equivalents - type :
>   sonata_type_collection - mapping :

I have tried setting `by_reference` to both `true` and `false`, and neither setting seemed to change anything. I have also run `doctrine:schema:validate` and spotted no problems. I have also verified that I am able to add and edit Equivalent objects in my CMS.

**What can I do to fix this?**

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that this problem involved an ORM mapping that was not getting read.

(The piece of logic where the complaint lived was checking for one of several ORM mapping types, then complaining if none of those types was found.)

Running `app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata` and then re-running my `doctrine:schema:update --force` command was enough to get my application to recognize the many-to-many relationship that I had been trying to put in place. This got rid of the cranky message.