# Sonata Media Bundle - INVALID MODE

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I am using Sonata Admin Bundle and Sonata Media Bundle. I use those versions. Symfony Version is `4.4.3`

```
sonata-project/admin-bundle              3.58.0     The missing Symfony Admin Generator
sonata-project/block-bundle              3.18.3     Symfony SonataBlockBundle
sonata-project/cache                     2.0.1      Cache library
sonata-project/core-bundle               3.17.2     Symfony SonataCoreBundle (abandoned)
sonata-project/datagrid-bundle           2.5.0      Symfony SonataDatagridBundle
sonata-project/doctrine-extensions       1.5.1      Doctrine2 behavioral extensions
sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 3.13.0     Symfony Sonata / Integrate Doctrine ORM into the SonataAdminBundle
sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle       2.5.0      Symfony SonataEasyExtendsBundle
sonata-project/exporter                  2.0.1      Lightweight Exporter library
sonata-project/media-bundle              3.23.0     Symfony SonataMediaBundle
```

Furthermore I use the GalleryAdmin provided by the Media Bundle without any changes. In the Gallery Edit case I get following error:

```
INVALID MODE : s5e37f8b81382b_galleryHasMedias - type : CollectionType - mapping :
```

This error message is printed where the upload / edit forms of the Gallery Media Items should be:

[image]

There are few other people having the same error but i haven't found a working solution to it. Does someone know how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this for you.
Maybe this could help, it looks like the error is comming from the ORM. You have to run `app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata` and then re-running `doctrine:schema:update --force`

source : [INVALID MODE : s5a869f19a6c57_equivalents - type : sonata_type_collection - mapping :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823406/invalid-mode-s5a869f19a6c57-equivalents-type-sonata-type-collection-mapp/48827920#48827920)